# Slick Slides on Pagination Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I actually want my slick slider to slide when I hover the paginations. I setup a jQuery to do that but it's not working.

```
jQuery('.slick-dots li').on('mouseover', function() {
      // console.log('hover');
      jQuery(this).parents('.slide').slick('goTo', jQuery(this).index());
});
```

Here is a Codepen Example:
[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/sabipu/pen/EypdBE)

Comment: Hey, just change `.slide` to `.slider` ! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzBxzP

Comment: OMG !!! sorry. such a dumbass i am !!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply trigger the element on mouseover

```
jQuery('.slick-dots li').on('mouseover', function() {
      jQuery(this).trigger('click');
});
```